# "All page should looks good" Is it correct?

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one is correct:

> 1. All page should look good
> 2. All pages should looks good
> 3. All page should looking good.

Please help me. I am confused of those sentences.

Comment: You don’t even tell us what you’re trying to say. You should elaborate more and improve this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends if you are talking about multiple pages or the single page. If you are talking about presenting a single page without any errors and in a neat manner, you would write it with a determiner: 'All ***THE*** page should look good.'

If what you are referring to has multiple pages, you would need the determiner as well as the plural form of page 'pages', so: 'All ***the*** page*S* should look good.' Or, you could drop the determiner 'the' and have: 'All page*s* should look good.'

Comment: I think “All the page should look good” reads rather awkwardly. I’d suggest, “The whole (or _entire_) page should look good."